# Startup Application with unknown source

Tags: gnome, autostart, abiword

After update to 15.04 I have `abiword` starting by itself upon login to GNOME or Unity. It does not happen in openbox or blackbox.

**How do I prevent this application from starting without removing the application itself ?**

I do not have abiword added to Startup Application, nor to `.config/autostart`, nor it is in `/etc/xdg/autostart`. The `rc.local` is clean, as well.

```
(=^・^=) [2] serg @ ubuntu:/home/xieerqi
>_  ls .config/autostart/                               
caribou-autostart.desktop
chinese-calendar-autostart.desktop
chromium-browser.desktop.bak
firefox.desktop
gnome-do.desktop
gnome-terminal.desktop.bak
gnome-user-share.desktop
indicator-multiload.desktop
lxrandr-autostart.desktop
nemo-autostart.desktop
reconnect-task.desktop
scrlayout.desktop
telepathy-indicator.desktop
ubuntuone-launch.desktop
vino-server.desktop
wicd-tray.desktop.bak

(=^・^=) [3] serg @ ubuntu:/home/xieerqi
>_  grep 'abiword' .config/autostart/*                  

(=^・^=) [4] serg @ ubuntu:/home/xieerqi
>_  grep 'abiword' /etc/xdg/autostart/*                 

(=^・^=) [5] serg @ ubuntu:/home/xieerqi
>_
```

`pstree` however, reports `upstart` as the parent of abiword's process.

```
(=^・^=) [6] serg @ ubuntu:/home/xieerqi
>_  pstree | grep abiword
        |         |         |-upstart-+-abiword-+-{abiword}
```

Better look:

```
|-lightdm-+-kwalletd
        |         |         |-upstart-+-abiword-+-{abiword}
        |         |         |         |         |-{dconf worker}
        |         |         |         |         |-{gdbus}
        |         |         |         |         `-{gmain}
```

Comment: What's the output of `grep --ignore-case abiword /etc/*`?

Comment: @Fabby I am pretty sure you meant `/etc/xdg/*` but for `/etc/*` I just get error for folders. There's some mention of abiword in `/etc/mailcap`  file, though, and also in `/etc/mime.types`.   [pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11344958/)

Comment: I should have be more specific,sorry!  **:-(**  Please post the output of `sudo grep --recursive --ignore-case abiword /etc/*` to http://paste.ubuntu.com so I can compare

Comment: @Fabby [Posted](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11354369/)

Comment: The same happened to me. I switched to Libreoffice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug. Therefore a simple hack:

```
sudo rm -f /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Telepathy.Client.AbiCollab.service
```

This file is created by `abiword-common`.

<sub>[Source](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/abiword/+bug/1432271)</sub>

Comment: That  did the trick !

Comment: O_o How did you find this one?

Comment: @Fabby Google? ;)